# How to setup constraints to invade another view

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

I always heard to set constraints to kind have a distance from view to view, but i would like to know if it is possible to set a view to invade another one.

My problem is, if you look on the image, you see 2 views, a soccer ball and a big white square.

Final result would be like this:

[image: Final result would be like this]

I would like to set a constraints to be like the image, the ball always get some space inside the white square view, it is possible to do something like that or i just need to go on paint, photoshop, or some other software to create an image like i pretend to have and don't worry about constraints anymore (like a work around).

Comment: Yes, of course you can set constraints to have one view overlap another view. Have you tried it?

Comment: Good to know @DonMag, do you know how? Or where i can find resources that teach this? I've been searching for a while but did not find any resource about it.

Comment: It's really just basic auto-layout... There are hundreds (probably thousands) of auto-layout tutorials / articles / blog posts / documentation out there. Best way to learn is to work through a bunch of them, and then just try different things yourself.

Comment: @DonMag so i just need to search by "overlaping"?

Comment: It's unlikely you'll find much by searching for "overlapping" ... take a look at the layout in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with basic auto-layout -- there is absolutely nothing wrong with constraining views so they overlap.

Here's a quick example:

[image]

Note the last constraint in the outline on the left:

```
BoxView.top = ball.bottom - 24
```

That puts the bottom of the image view 24-pts below the top of the "box" view... in other words, it has a 24-pt "overlap."

---

**Edit**

By swapping the constraint order, it may be a little more clear:

[image]

Now, the last constraint shows:

```
ball.bottom = BoxView.top + 24
```

which may be a little more intuitive.

---

**Edit 2**

Regarding your comment - that the ball image view is covered by the grey box view...

I cannot replicate it, but I've seen this happen before with image views. Even using `Debug View Hierarchy` shows the image view in front of the other view, but it gets rendered as if it was behind it. In the cases where I've seen it, re-making the controller in Storyboard has fixed the issue.

However, it might not, so...

Assuming you have the image view connected to an outlet, you can try this:

```
@IBOutlet var ball: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    view.bringSubviewToFront(ball)
}
```

Comment: I think i am almost there @DonMag, the ball image view is getting the right space with the square view, but when i compile, it get behind the square: https://imgur.com/a/k7NlUD9

I've tried to change thins hierarchily, but it keep going behind the white square view.
I tried even using your boxview.bottom = 120 but it did not worked, probably it is not related but i tested anyway

Comment: @virtu - see my **Edit 2** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: it is working now with viewDidLayoutSubview() method! Thank you very much.
Do you think is a good try build it from zero again to test your comment about "e-making the controller in Storyboard has fixed the issue." to make my code independent of that viewDidLayoutSubview() method?

Comment: Btw, never heard about that viewDidLayoutSubview()  method, probably because i am starting on this life of swift developer, but thanks anyway.